# trying to install ruby oci8 with bundle install and i tried doing it seperate still not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, bundler

```
@ubuntu:~/contract-review$ bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..


 Resolving dependencies...
    Using rake 10.1.0
    Using i18n 0.6.1
    Using multi_json 1.8.2
    Using activesupport 3.2.13
    Using builder 3.0.4
    Using activemodel 3.2.13
    Using erubis 2.7.0
    Using journey 1.0.4
    Using rack 1.4.5
    Using rack-cache 1.2
    Using rack-test 0.6.2
    Using hike 1.2.3
    Using tilt 1.4.1
    Using sprockets 2.2.2
    Using actionpack 3.2.13
    Using mime-types 1.23
    Using polyglot 0.3.3
    Using treetop 1.4.14
    Using mail 2.5.4
    Using actionmailer 3.2.13
    Using arel 3.0.2
    Using tzinfo 0.3.37
    Using activerecord 3.2.13
    Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.4.2
    Using activeresource 3.2.13
    Using net-ldap 0.3.1
    Using adauth 1.2.1
    Using addressable 2.3.5
    Using json 1.8.1
    Using airbrake 3.1.12
    Using rack-ssl 1.3.3
    Using rdoc 3.12.2
    Using thor 0.18.1
    Using railties 3.2.13
    Using jquery-rails 1.0.19
    Using bundler 1.6.3
    Using rails 3.2.13
    Using best_in_place 2.1.0
    Using bootstrap-sass 2.0.4.2
    Using cancan 1.6.10
    Using highline 1.6.19
    Using net-ssh 2.6.7
    Using net-scp 1.1.1
    Using net-sftp 2.1.2
    Using net-ssh-gateway 1.2.0
    Using capistrano 2.12.0
    Using mini_portile 0.5.1
    Using nokogiri 1.6.0
    Using xpath 2.0.0
    Using capybara 2.1.0
    Using ffi 1.9.0
    Using childprocess 0.3.9
    Using chronic 0.9.1
    Using coderay 1.0.9
    Using coffee-script-source 1.6.3
    Using execjs 1.4.0
    Using coffee-script 2.2.0
    Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
    Using composite_primary_keys 5.0.13
    Using database_cleaner 0.7.2
    Using diff-lcs 1.2.4
    Using factory_girl 4.2.0
    Using factory_girl_rails 4.2.1
    Using sass 3.2.12
    Using sass-rails 3.2.6
    Using font-awesome-sass-rails 3.0.2.2
    Using formatador 0.2.4
    Using rb-fsevent 0.9.3
    Using rb-inotify 0.9.0
    Using rb-kqueue 0.2.0
    Using listen 1.2.2
    Using lumberjack 1.0.4
    Using method_source 0.8.2
    Using slop 3.4.6
    Using pry 0.9.12.2
    Using guard 1.8.2
    Using rspec-core 2.14.4
    Using rspec-expectations 2.14.0
    Using rspec-mocks 2.14.2
    Using rspec 2.14.1
    Using guard-rspec 3.0.2
    Using haml 4.0.3
    Using haml-rails 0.4
    Using iconv 1.0.3
    Using jquery-scrollto-rails 1.4.2
    Using jquery-ui-rails 4.0.3
    Using jquery-ui-sass-rails 4.0.3.0
    Using kaminari 0.14.1
    Using launchy 2.3.0
    Using libv8 3.11.8.17
    Using quiet_assets 1.0.2
    Using ref 1.0.5
    Using rspec-rails 2.14.0

    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
    checking for load library path... 
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH... 
        checking /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib... no
      checking ld.so.conf... no
    checking for cc... ok
    checking for gcc... yes
    checking for LP64... no
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for ruby header... ok
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-instant-client
    --without-instant-client
/tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:889:in `get_home': RuntimeError (RuntimeError)
    from /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:705:in `initialize'
    from /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `new'
    from /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `get'
    from extconf.rb:18:in `<main>'



 Error Message:
      Set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME if Oracle Full Client.
      Append the path of Oracle client libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if Oracle Instant Client.

Backtrace:
  /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:889:in `get_home'
  /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:705:in `initialize'
  /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `new'
  /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `get'
  extconf.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20140624-4932-e7ymvw/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ruby-oci8 (2.1.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-oci8 -v '2.1.5'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compile the native extension gem ruby-oci8, whcih is required for active record oracle adapter, it needs to know the path to the oracle client.

```
  #check the path of your Oracle instanant client install
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

 $ bundle install
```